# React - Reading text area value from a grandparent using refs

Tags: reactjs, textarea

I have a grandparent, a parent and a child component with a textarea. I need to read the value on the textarea from a function in the grandparent component. All 3 are classes,

In the child component textarea I am doing this

```
<textarea            
        name={this.props.name}
        id={this.props.id}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        value={this.props.value}
        ref="someref"
>
```

The grandparent is trying to access the textarea ref like this

```
console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.someref))
```

And I get a null value.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? It is very possible that you could achieve the same thing using other, cleaner way.

Comment: @Jackyef I wanted to read the value of the textarea using refs on clicking Save on the form. The saving function is on the grandparent, and so i was trying to read the value of the textarea in the child component without having to pass it to parent and from there to grandparent, if i could. Thanks

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is to actually have that value as a state at the grandparent component. The grandparent will pass the value and an onChange handler to the parent, and then to the text area. The textarea should just use that value, the onChange handler as well. The grandparent would always have the value because the value is stored in its own state.

Comment: @Jackyef yes, thanks, I was trying not to have to migrate my functions which are on the parent to the grandparent. I think i found how to do it using Refs, i will post the answer shortly, but I  am not sure it is a good practice what i am doing

Comment: Usually, you would want the top-most component to store the value and provide all the functions, so you could have it as the source of truth. There's nothing wrong with migrating functions or refactoring, while might be scary, could actually improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did was

On the grandparent, on calling the parent

```
<Parent
  someRef={(textarea) => {this.someRef = textarea;}}
  ...
  ...
/>
```

On the parent, when calling the child

```
<Child
  someRef={this.props.someRef}
  ...
  ...
/>
```

And on the child that calls the textarea

```
<textarea
  ref={this.props.someRef}
>
```

And I access it from the grandparent like this

```
this.someRef.value
```

Please if someone sees this as wrong post it in the comments